# Which monsters are immune to Black Hole's vortex?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Black Hole has no "pull" effect on some monsters, as I observe. And as far as I could see,  these are the larger ones.

Under what circumstances does the vortex affect monsters? Elites, champions? 
Does the damage still apply even though the vortex does not?

Comment: it seems to affect most things, though not big things like you said, wurms, and rift bosses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all bosses are affected. The damage is still applied,  though.

You cannot move rooted monsters like worms and hives, these will report 'immune'  when a Black Hole goes off near them.

Also, there is a "weight" assigned to monsters, that affects how much they move from things like knockback. Any ordinary monster above that threshhold will not be pulled toward the black hole, but still takes damage.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  Any mob with a purple name is considered a boss and I've been able to vortex several bosses before.  I'm not sure if it'll work on Act End Bosses - but most bosses in the game can and are affected by it depending on their size.

Comment: @Mkalafut I wasn't counting purple bosses such as rift bosses etc...I was mainly talking about end-act bosses and sub-act bosses like Ghom. But yes, you are correct. It mainly depends on their size or more accurately, their weight.

Comment: I don't think i've managed to affect a single rift boss with black hole...  @Mkalafut and no, super uniques are purple but not bosses

Answer (score -7):

As far as i am concerned, only end game bosses are affected by black hole pull and their effects included.